# Create JSON Array with object name android

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I want to create `JSONArray` like this

[image]

when i add json object in array it will format like this

[image]

**My Code:**

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
object.put("calories_burn", "345");
object.put("time", dp.getTimestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject();
object1.put("calories", object);
array.put(object1);
```

Comment: Create a list of json object with there identifier and transform the list into json array

Comment: i'm confused what you are trying to do. 
Are you trying to create an array and in that array an object with the name of android and withing that object a new array with steps, calories etc.

Or is your array named android and you want it to contain objects steps, calories, bpm?

Comment: i want to create `can you make this` format as shown in first image.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin how can i add identifier to a json object? i dint find any method for that?

Answer (score 2):

You are falling in between two patterns, you can either use it as a map, or an array.

Map approach:

```
{
  "steps": { "steps":123, "time": 123 },
  "calories": { and so},
  "bpm": { on }
}
```

Code (untested, think and tweak)

```
// Build your objects
JSONObject steps = new JSONObject();
steps.put("steps", 123);
steps.put("time" 123);
JSONObject calories = new JSONObject();
//And so on
JSONObject bpm = new JSONObject();

//Make a map
JSONObject map = new JSONObject();
//Add to the map:
map.put("steps", steps);
map.put("calories", calories);
map.put("bpm", bpm);
```

Comment: how can i do this in java

Comment: its still not created array {"steps":{"steps":"27200","time":1485287743921},"calories":{"calories_burn":4953,"time":1485287743921},"bpm":{"bpm":83,"time":1485287743921}}

Comment: I already told you that you can either chose to do an array or a map, you already succeeded in making an array, and I showed you how to make a map, the code you show me is exactly as shown in my example.
What you ask for in your example, is not valid json.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add keys inside a JSONArray. You can do that inside a JSONObject though.

Two approaches:

1. With JSONArray (Acts Like A List):

   ```
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

   JSONObject caloriesJSON = new JSONObject();
   caloriesJSON.put("calories_burn", 345);
   caloriesJSON.put("time", dp.getTimestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

   JSONObject stepsJSON = new JSONObject();
   stepsJSON.put("steps", "12121");
   stepsJSON.put("time", dp.getTimestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

   jsonArray.put(stepsJSON);
   jsonArray.put(caloriesJSON);
   ```
2. With JSONObject(Acts Like A Map/Dictionary):

   ```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

   JSONObject caloriesJSON = new JSONObject();
   caloriesJSON.put("calories_burn", 345);
   caloriesJSON.put("time", dp.getTimestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

   JSONObject stepsJSON = new JSONObject();
   stepsJSON.put("steps", "12121");
   stepsJSON.put("time", dp.getTimestamp(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

   jsonObject.put("steps",  stepsJSON);
   jsonObject.put("calories", caloriesJSON);
   ```

Be careful what you put for values. "12313" is a String whereas 345 is an integer.